# How to load the same page in a dialog in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a page with many dojo widgets. I need to load the portion of the same page in the dialog without conflicting the widgets. 
Will iframe inside the dialog helps me?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive with your question? It is difficult for us to gather what is going on here. I can't see why or how a portion of the page is being loaded or why or how dojo widgets would conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant have duplicates of widgets, you can try using dojo.place to move them into your dialog temporarily, then move them back out.